# Propagating flashing lights

Tags: led

I have some equipment that is mounted some distance from the front panel on the wrong side.  It has some flashing LEDs which are used to indicate whether the equipment is ready, in an error state etc.  I am looking for an off the shelf method for bringing the flashing light to the front panel.

```
 ___________________
|  ________         |
| |        |        |
| |________|        |
|    *   *          |   <- LEDs on the device
|                   |
|___________________|
                 * *    <- Where they should appear in the front panel
```

I had a look at the PCs - they have the LED just behind some clear perspex: not 30cm away on the wrong side.  All the cables are already the correct length so I can't shift the equipment.  I don't know if cutting the perspex with a handsaw would dull it too much.

I had a look at optical fibre - it is really thin and does not emit enough light.

Is there a simple way of bringing the flashing light to the front panel?

Comment: Would a [light pipe](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/bivar-inc/SMFLP6-0/2407240) work for you?

Comment: Can you solder a wire to move the led from PCB to the front panel?

Comment: This question is a bit broad to fit here, and the "off the shelf" request makes it sounds like a prohibited "shopping question".  Depending on your comfort level and the number of copies needed, remoting the LEDs on wires may be an option.  Many sub-modules (at least better ones) have status output *signals* or *status register bits* which could be read by something in the host system and used to re-generate status lights elsewhere.

Comment: If they are throug-hole LEDs you  may be able to replace them with 2-pin headers. The rest is easy.

Comment: think nanofarad's answer is the right direction, my mechanical colleagues design and simulate light guides for our products, so I guess you should ask this in a mechanical / synthetic material forum. You need somebody with experience in 3D CAD and FEM simulations

Comment: @nanofarad Haven't heard of a light pipe before but that looks like it might work.  If you write that as the solution, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @cup Added an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A light pipe, such as [this example](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/bivar-inc/SMFLP6-0/2407240), is often used for this purpose. For example, I've seen these used to get status LEDs from a PCB of a disk enclosure on a server, to the front panel of each drive carrier.

Digikey and other distributors carry the flexible variety in a number of lengths, ranging from a few mm to over a meter.